# Can someone tell me the output and provide explanation of the following c++ code?

Tags: c++, c++11, output, c++14

```
cout<<"#" + 'a'<<endl;

string s = "#";
s += 'a';
cout<<s<<endl;
```

I am not able to figure out how the typecasting is working in the case `"#" + 'a'`

Comment: *"how the typecasting is working in the case `"#" + 'a'`"* - `"#" + 'a'` generates a pointer-arithmetic calculation you most-certainly do *not* want.

Comment: `"#" + 'a'` is Undefined Behaviour, the output can be anything.

Comment: I am getting some weird output for the first one i.e. "#" + 'a'. 
Tried it on leetcode and there was a runtime error. 
Compiling it locally with g++ compiler on Ubuntu 20.04 prints nothing.

Comment: Yes, that what @Yksisarvinen said, "the output could be anything". It can be even hardware crash :D

Comment: @WhozCraig and Yksisarvinen can you refer some links to read more about it

Comment: You can try `typeid("#"+'a').name()` and `const char* test = NULL; typeid(test).name()`. You will get both same I think. It means output is considered a pointer.

Comment: `"#"` is `const char[2]` (`{'#', '\0'}`) which decays to `const char*`.

Comment: @TusharGupta you put "c++ pointer arithmetic" in any search engine and you'll have reading material for hours.

Comment: Thank @Jarod42 and everyone I got it now. I am adding a `char* to a char` that is getting typecasted into int.So basically I am doing `char* + int`. Hence the weird output.

Comment: Anyone of you folks can add it as answer and I will accept it :)

Comment: There is no typecasting in this code. The question is about an **implicit conversion**. A cast is something you write in your source code to tell the compiler to do a conversion.

Answer (score -1):

In cpp string works like an array of characters, so when you assign s = '#' it compiles like this:

```
s[0] = '#'
```

and in the second line it actually compiles like this:

```
s[1] = 'a'
```

finally, s is:

```
#a
```

Comment: `cout<<"#" + 'a'<<endl` Can you explain the output for this one. The explanation for second one is correct.

Comment: It might be useful to show the implied `s.resize(1)` and `s.resize(s.size()+1)`. But still, this doesn't answer the interesting bit.